# NHibernate From One-To-Many to One-To-One

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, one-to-many, one-to-one

I am creating the security system for the software im creating and I would like to know how i can do the following in NHibernate(if at all possible)

User Account Class:

```
public class UserAccount
{
    public virtual int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual String Username { get; set; }
    public virtual Privilege InvoicePrivilege { get; set; }
    public virtual Privilege TradePrivilege { get; set; }
}
```

Privilege Class:

```
public class Privilege
{
    public virtual bool Read { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Write { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Delete { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Modify { get; set; }
}
```

I will be having a large number of these privilege objects (one for each traded entity) so in the database i have the following tables:

UserAccounts ( **UserID**, Username)
Privileges (**UserID, PrivilegeType**, Read,Write,Modify,Delete)

How can I map the InvoicePrivielge property from the user account to the (UserID, 'Invoice') Privilege.

I could do this using many-to-one but I don't want a collection of privileges, i'd rather map it to its property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a way to do this is to create two subclasses of the Privilege class:

```
public class InvoicePrivilege : Privilege 
{
}
public class TradePrivilege : Privilege
{
}
```

and set the discriminator column and value. In fluent mapping:

```
public class PrivilegeMap : ClassMap<Privilege>
{
  public PrivilegeMap()
  { 
     // ...
     DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("PrivilegeType")
       .SubClass<InvoicePrivilege>("Invoice", x => x.Map( ... ))
       .SubClass<TradePrivilege>("Trade", x => x.Map( ...));
  }
}
```

and use the subclasses in the `UserAccount`

```
public virtual InvoicePrivilege InvoicePrivilege { get; set; }
public virtual TradePrivilege TradePrivilege { get; set; }
```

Comment: I don't have Fluent nhibernate, any way to do this is in normal nhibernate? It seems like a good way of doing it :)